# CasperJS/PhantomJS, some tests fail randomly

Tags: javascript, testing, random, phantomjs, casperjs

I have some scenarios in which some tests fail randomly (maybe 5/65), often with svg, auto-completion, etc... The CPU is fine though, so it comes from my way to script it.

But I don't see how to alter them to make them robust and reliable. It's when I use wait() function -> sometimes I have the timeout error, sometimes it passes.

The strangest is that when i split my script in two script, there are less fails than with one ....

---

**Add waitForResource try**

*Thx to Artjom B. for the help.*

```
casper.test.begin('\n********* Navigation on directories : ***********', 4,{
setUp: function(test) {
    setLevel("normal");
},

tearDown: function(test) {
    getJSON();
},

test: function(test){
    "use strict";
    var url = 'http://www.linternaute.com/';
    casper.start()
   .thenOpen(url + "/ville/", function(){
        if(this.exists('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close')){this.click('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close');}
        if(this.exists('#top_oas')){this.click('#top_oas > .right');}
        this.test.assertExists(".jODMainSearch", "Search toolbar present");
        this.sendKeys(".jODMainSearch", "Ren");
        this.click(".submit.search");
    })
    .waitForSelector(".odListGlossary", function(){
        this.test.assertExists(".odListGlossary", "Search result ok");
        this.clickLabel("Rennes (35000)");
    })
    .waitFor(function check() {
            return this.fetchText('h1').indexOf("Rennes") !== -1;
            }
            , function then() {
                this.test.assertSelectorHasText("h1", "Rennes");
            }
    )
    //auto-completion
    .thenOpen(url + "/ville/", function(){

        //this.waitForResource(/odmainsearch/, function(){
            /*var fs = require('fs');
            fs.write("results1.html", this.getPageContent(), 'w');
            this.wait(8000, function(){
                var fs = require('fs');
            fs.write("results2.html", this.getPageContent(), 'w');
            });*/

            /*casper.waitFor(function check() {
                    return this.fetchText('script').indexOf("fn.odMainsearch=function") !== -1;
                    }
                    , function then() {
                        this.echo('cc');
                        this.sendKeys('.jODMainSearch', 'Ren', {keepFocus: true});
                    }
            );*/
        /*** the changes ***/   
        this.waitForResource(function testResource(resource) {
            return resource.url.indexOf("http://static.ccmbg.com/www.linternaute.com/asset/js?m=odmainsearch") !== -1;
        }, function onReceived() {
            this.echo('JS for auto-completion present');
            this.sendKeys('.jODMainSearch', 'Ren', {keepFocus: true});
        });
        this.waitForSelector('ul.ui-autocomplete[viewbox="true"]', function() {
            this.mouse.move('a[href="/ville/rennes/ville-35238"]');
            this.click('a[href="/ville/rennes/ville-35238"]');
        });
    })
    .waitFor(function check() {
            return this.fetchText('h1').indexOf("Rennes") !== -1;
            }
            , function then() {
                this.test.assertSelectorHasText("h1", "Rennes");
            }
    )
    .run(function() {
            this.test.comment('--- Done ---\n');
            test.done();
    });
}
});
```

---

**First try :**

Here an example which randomly fails :

```
casper.test.begin('\n********* Navigation on directories : ***********', 4,{
setUp: function(test) {
    //setLevel("normal");
},

tearDown: function(test) {
    //getJSON();
},

test: function(test){
    "use strict";
    var url = 'http://www.linternaute.com/';
    casper.start()
   .thenOpen(url + "/ville/", function(){
        //close some ads
        if(this.exists('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close')){this.click('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close');}
        if(this.exists('#top_oas')){this.click('#top_oas > .right');}
        this.test.assertExists(".jODMainSearch", "Search toolbar present");
        this.sendKeys(".jODMainSearch", "Ren");
        this.click(".submit.search");
    })
    .waitForSelector(".odListGlossary", function(){
        this.test.assertExists(".odListGlossary", "Search result ok");
        this.clickLabel("Rennes (35000)");
    })
    .waitFor(function check() {
            return this.fetchText('h1').indexOf("Rennes") !== -1;
            }
            , function then() {
                this.test.assertSelectorHasText("h1", "Rennes");
            }
    )
    //auto-completion
    .thenOpen(url + "/ville/", function(){
        this.sendKeys('.jODMainSearch', 'Ren', {keepFocus: true});
        this.waitForSelector('ul.ui-autocomplete[viewbox="true"]', function() {
            this.mouse.move('a[href="/ville/rennes/ville-35238"]');
            this.click('a[href="/ville/rennes/ville-35238"]');
        });
    })
    .waitFor(function check() {
            return this.fetchText('h1').indexOf("Rennes") !== -1;
            }
            , function then() {
                this.test.assertSelectorHasText("h1", "Rennes");
            }
    )
    .run(function() {
            this.test.comment('--- Done ---\n');
            test.done();
    });
}
});
```

And if I take just the end of the script (where it randomly fails in the first example, I've commented the beginning) :

```
casper.test.begin('\n********* Navigation on directories : ***********', 1,{
setUp: function(test) {
    //setLevel("normal");
},

tearDown: function(test) {
    //getJSON();
},

test: function(test){
    "use strict";
    var url = 'http://www.linternaute.com/';
    casper.start()
   /*.thenOpen(url + "/ville/", function(){
        if(this.exists('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close')){this.click('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close');}
        if(this.exists('#top_oas')){this.click('#top_oas > .right');}
        this.test.assertExists(".jODMainSearch", "Search toolbar present");
        this.sendKeys(".jODMainSearch", "Ren");
        this.click(".submit.search");
    })
    .waitForSelector(".odListGlossary", function(){
        this.test.assertExists(".odListGlossary", "Search result ok");
        this.clickLabel("Rennes (35000)");
    })
    .waitFor(function check() {
            return this.fetchText('h1').indexOf("Rennes") !== -1;
            }
            , function then() {
                this.test.assertSelectorHasText("h1", "Rennes");
            }
    )*/
    //auto-completion
    .thenOpen(url + "/ville/", function(){
        this.sendKeys('.jODMainSearch', 'Ren', {keepFocus: true});
        this.waitForSelector('ul.ui-autocomplete[viewbox="true"]', function() {
            this.mouse.move('a[href="/ville/rennes/ville-35238"]');
            this.click('a[href="/ville/rennes/ville-35238"]');
        });
    })
    .waitFor(function check() {
            return this.fetchText('h1').indexOf("Rennes") !== -1;
            }
            , function then() {
                this.test.assertSelectorHasText("h1", "Rennes");
            }
    )
    .run(function() {
            this.test.comment('--- Done ---\n');
            test.done();
    });
}
});
```

So what's the problem, do you have an idea? -> Two step functions in the stack : it often fails, only one : it sometimes fails...

Comment: The strange thing is that by extending the wait period with `casper.options.waitTimeout = 10000;` the test fails everytime and the reduced test sometimes.

Comment: If I go manually on the page, and try to use the auto-completion (manually too) before all the js is loaded on the page, it doesn't launch the auto-complete block. The problem is a `thenOpen()` wait for all the js to be executed before doing the first step (and I can confirm it with the debug option). So the auto-complete should appear. When it passes : `[info] [phantom] waitFor() finished in 40ms.` So I don't know why but there is an issue where some JS seem ignored... It's bad :s

Comment: You could identify all the js that is necessary for the autocomplete to run and do `waitForRessource` between `thenOpen` and `sendKeys` (inside `then`).

Comment: Yes, I could, but it means when you are not testing your own website, it's quite annoying if you have to look for the ressource each time... And indeed it works with a wait() before the sendKeys. So it seems I was wrong, thenOpen() doesn't wait for js to be executed, it seems it waits for `DOM ready` and not something similar to `window.onload`... In fact no because when you look at pageContent() it seems js has been executed, I don't understand **

Comment: It seems that some of the js is loaded later (from the inline script block?) `http://static.ccmbg.com/www.linternaute.com/asset/js?m=odmainsearch&v=201405201800` which contains the search. There's nothing you can do but to specifically wait for it.

Comment: Well, it's asynchronous js apparently so yes I need to wait for it. It's still strange because if I take the pageContent() just after thenOpen(); the script is present in the page. But it works by waiting the resource (which is already present xD but nevermind, maybe there is another call or something... ), write your comment in answer i will accept it. I've edited the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like not all scripts are present in the DOM when loading the page. At least one of the js resources is loaded later after an evaluation of an inline script block and is therefore loaded after `window.onload` and accordingly after `thenOpen` gives the control to the next step. The resource in your case is:

```
http://static.ccmbg.com/www.linternaute.com/asset/js?m=odmainsearch&v=201405201‌​800
```

So you need to wait for such a late resource if you want to take action based on its code. In your case it is necessary for the autocomplete dropdown to open. So I changed

```js
casper.thenOpen(url + "/ville/", function(){
    this.sendKeys('.jODMainSearch', 'Ren', {keepFocus: true});
    this.waitForSelector('ul.ui-autocomplete[viewbox="true"]', function() {
        this.mouse.move('a[href="/ville/rennes/ville-35238"]');
        this.click('a[href="/ville/rennes/ville-35238"]');
    });
});
```

to

```js
casper.thenOpen(url + "/ville/")
.waitForResource(/linternaute\.com\/asset\/js/, function(){
    this.wait(500); // this seem necessary: maybe to wait for the script evaluation
})
.then(function(){
    this.sendKeys('.jODMainSearch', 'Ren', {keepFocus: true});
})
.waitForSelector('ul.ui-autocomplete[viewbox="true"]', function() {
    this.mouse.move('a[href="/ville/rennes/ville-35238"]');
    this.click('a[href="/ville/rennes/ville-35238"]');
});
```

I used the complete script without uncommenting the first part. The `casper` is only there for orientation. 20 runs without an error.

Comment: Arf, I just got an error :p Well I will just loop on sendKeys (every second) when the auto-completion doesn't appear until the global timeout. The test will be reliable that way.

Comment: @Fanch Strange, maybe increase the inner `this.wait(1000)`? Or just wait 2000 msec before `sendKeys`.

Comment: It could work but it means sometimes we'll loose some seconds :p But I'm lazy so I'll try :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a precision to make the test definitively reliable :

```
casper.test.begin('\n********* Navigation : ***********', 4,{
setUp: function(test) {
    //setLevel("normal");
},

tearDown: function(test) {
    //getJSON();
},

test: function(test){
    "use strict";
    var url = 'http://www.linternaute.com/';
    casper.start()
   .thenOpen(url + "/ville/", function(){
        if(this.exists('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close')){this.click('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close');}
        if(this.exists('#top_oas')){this.click('#top_oas > .right');}
        this.test.assertExists(".jODMainSearch", "Search toolbar present");
        this.sendKeys(".jODMainSearch", "Ren");
        this.click(".submit.search");
    })
    .waitForSelector(".odListGlossary", function(){
        this.test.assertExists(".odListGlossary", "Search result ok");
        this.clickLabel("Rennes (35000)");
    })
    .waitFor(function check() {
            return this.fetchText('h1').indexOf("Rennes") !== -1;
            }
            , function then() {
                this.test.assertSelectorHasText("h1", "Rennes");
            }
    )
    //auto-completion
    .thenOpen(url + "ville/")
    .waitForResource(/linternaute\.com\/asset\/js/, function(){
        this.wait(1000); // this seem necessary: maybe to wait for the script evaluation of 'http://static.ccmbg.com/www.linternaute.com/asset/js?m=odmainsearch&v=201405201‌​800'
    })
    .then(function(){
        this.sendKeys('.jODMainSearch', 'Ren', {keepFocus: true});
        this.waitFor(function checkAutoComplete(){
            return this.exists('ul.ui-autocomplete[viewbox="true"]');
            }
            , function then() {
                this.mouse.move('a[href="/ville/rennes/ville-35238"]');
                this.click('a[href="/ville/rennes/ville-35238"]');
            }
            , function timeout() { 
                // step to execute if checkAutoComplete has failed, it makes the test reliable if there is a freeze
                // or something wrong in the execution of the previous resource. 1 build on 50 fails without that. 
                // Like that you haven't to wait 5~9sec in waitForResource to be 'sure'.
                this.sendKeys('.jODMainSearch', 'n', {keepFocus: true});
                this.waitForSelector('ul.ui-autocomplete[viewbox="true"]', function() {
                    this.mouse.move('a[href="/ville/rennes/ville-35238"]');
                    this.click('a[href="/ville/rennes/ville-35238"]');
                });
            }
        );
    })
    .waitFor(function check() {
            return this.fetchText('h1').indexOf("Rennes") !== -1;
            }
            , function then() {
                this.test.assertSelectorHasText("h1", "Rennes");
            }
    )
    .run(function() {
            this.test.comment('--- Done ---\n');
            test.done();
    });
}
});
```